# Downgrade from TortoiseSVN version 1.8 to 1.7.7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have upgraded to 1.8 version and made some changes and checked- in the code. later I realized that other team members are using 1.7.7. how can I revert back my 1.8 changes to 1.7.7 (format changes) and then re-install 1.7.7 version?

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of SVN is to take care of files for you. This means that SVN and SVN client will not change the files. They only store it. You don't have to worry about versions of TortoiseSVN, and you shouldn't have to downgrade the version that is installed on your computer. Everything works fine now and will work fine in the future.

If there was some hypothetical problem it would be shown when committing changes with 1.8 version.

The only reason to downgrade TortoiseSVN would be if different SVN clients manipulate the same working copy on your computer. Then these SVN clients would have to have the same version.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have uncommitted changes in your working copy, you can just delete it and checkout again with the 1.7.7 client.

The changes you committed with the 1.8 client are entirely compatible with the 1.7.7 clients. From the [1.8 release notes](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html):

```
Older clients and servers interoperate transparently with 1.8 servers and clients.
```

Comment: Will my 1.8 changes that I have already committed will effect 1.7.7 users?

Comment: No, all 1.x clients and servers speak the same protocol. It is only the working copy format that is often incompatible between client versions.